# Question regarding select and option value="" using JQuery

Tags: jquery, selectedindex

let's say i have list looking like this:

```
<select name="name" id="id">
    <option value="10176232332">David</option>
    <option value="10187232332">Sven</option>
    <option value="10202232332">Ololf</option>
    <option value="10219232323">Jan</option>
    <option value="10230232323">Gustaf</option>
</select>
```

Using JQuery, how can i extract the value for each option - for example:

```
<option value="10176232332">David</option>
```

Where 10176232332 is the value. Using:

```
($("#id").val())
```

extracts the names, not the number combinations. Using regluar Javascript i would use:

```
list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
```

Is there a "JQuery way" of doing that or should i stick to the above?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `val()` function only works for **input** elements (`input`, `select`, `textarea`, `button`). The `option` element is not an input element.

As said before, you need to handle it as a "normal" element, get it by `option.attr('value')`.

Comment: This is not quite true. val() does work on `option` elements according to <a href="http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val">official documentation.</a>

Answer (score 3):

```
var selected = $("#id option:selected");
var value = selected.val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

`$("#id").attr("value")`

...but it's been a while since I used jQuery.

Comment: There's no value attribute on the <select /> element, so this will give you nothing, basically.

Comment: Ah, yes. Umm...I *thought* it looked too obvious to be useful, I should've thought harder... =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you will be triggering an event handler to capture this information, correct? If so, here is how I would access a selected value's "id" and "name" components:

```
    $('select').change(function () { 
        var id = $(":selected", this).val();
        var name = $(":selected", this).text();
    });
```

`
There is a demo of this code in action [here](http://hcs.ufl.edu/~eriksen/jquery.html).